# Vue Router Dynamically set Meta

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

So I have a SPA using Vue and Vue Router. It is set up like an iOS app where when you click deeper into a view the title in the navbar changes. Right now I have this hardcoded in the routes.js file but would like to make it dynmaic. I can update the route meta within my view but that renders after the view is show so I need it to happen before route change. Here is the setup:

route.js

```
//A route
 {   
      path: '/team/:username', 
      component: require('./views/team-single'),  
      name: 'profile', 
      meta:{ requiresAuth: true, title: 'Team Member', tabbar: false } 
  }
```

navbar.vue

```
//if the route has a title show that not the logo
 <div class="navbar-item">

     <transition name="fadeup">
         <h1 v-if="$route.meta.title" class="navbar-title">{{ $route.meta.title }}</h1>
         <img src="/img/hopbak-green.svg" class="navbar-logo"  alt="hopbak" v-else>
     </transition>

 </div>
```

So ideally it would be nice to pass the :username into the title in the route.js but I dont think thats possible. I have tried adding something like this to a view but like I said it gets called to late:

team-member.vue

```
mounted(){
   this.$route.meta.title = this.user.username
}
```

which does change it but not before the navbar already loaded.

[image]

Comment: Could you add a `beforeRouteEnter` guard?

Answer (score 14):

I had a similar problem with dynamic url parameters in metadata and I solved it by evaluating the meta attribute of `this.$route` as function. First configure the meta attribute in this way:

```
//A route
 {   
      path: '/team/:username', 
      component: require('./views/team-single'),  
      name: 'profile', 
      meta: (route) => ({ requiresAuth: true, title: 'Team Member' + route.params.username, tabbar: false }) 
  }
```

Then you could use it in your template in this way:

```
//if the route has a title show that not the logo
 <div class="navbar-item">

     <transition name="fadeup">
         <h1 v-if="$route.meta != null" class="navbar-title">{{ $route.meta($route).title }}</h1>
         <img src="/img/hopbak-green.svg" class="navbar-logo"  alt="hopbak" v-else>
     </transition>

 </div>
```

Comment: I used this great idea for route permissions.  I set a function to a meta.permission prop for a named route and then call that function in router.beforeEach to get the permissions for that route and then compare to vuex store state for the user to determine if route goes ahead.  Works great!

Comment: How do you access it in JS?

Comment: In your vue component (e.g. in data() method), you are able to use it in that way: `let title = this.$route.meta(this.$route).title`.

Comment: To set the meta object as a function prevents the merging of its values to all matched routes.

Answer (score 8):

After setting the meta, I forced the router to reload like this:

```
this.$route.meta.title = this.user.username

// Add a temporary query parameter.
this.$router.replace({query: {temp: Date.now()}})
// Remove the temporary query parameter.
this.$router.replace({query: {temp: undefined}})
```

There are many workarounds to force a reload of the router found in this GitHub [issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/296). This is just one of them.

Answer (score 7):

You could use `props` to achieve something like this.

```
{
  path: '/team/:username',
  name: 'profile',
  component: require('./views/team-single'),
  props: (route) => ({ title: route.params.username })
}
```

And, in the component:

```
props: ['title'],
...
mounted () {
  console.log('title: ' + this.title)
}
...
```

Checkout docs for more: https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/passing-props.html

Comment: Thanks. A good solution, but it will only pass the prop to the component `team-single`. The title needs to be set in the in `navbar` component which is in the main app layout.

Comment: Then, one way would be to set and read the title from some kind of store. Checkout https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/

Comment: I had still the same problem. On adding dynamic url params to props (for provide this params to the specific componenent) is no problem. But providing this dyanmic url params to meta in routes not works:-( Same question was here: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vue-router-assign-param-as-meta-data/24817

Answer (score 2):

To set the `meta` object as a function prevents the merging of its values to all matched routes. From [docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/meta.html#route-meta-fields):

> ...Vue Router also provides you a `$route.meta` that is a non-recursive merge of all meta fields from parent to child.

The best soluction is to set the value of the specific meta property as a function. For example, using Pinia:

```js
meta: {
  title: () => useProjectsStore()?.currentItem?.title || 'Project dashboard',
}
```

Then, before to use its value, check its type:

```js
  {{
    typeof item.meta?.title === 'function' 
    ? item.meta.title()
    : item.meta?.title
  }}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// literal string path
router.push('/users/eduardo')

// object with path
router.push({ path: '/users/eduardo' })

// named route with params to let the router build the url
router.push({ name: 'user', params: { username: 'eduardo' } })

// with query, resulting in /register?plan=private
router.push({ path: '/register', query: { plan: 'private' } })

// with hash, resulting in /about#team
router.push({ path: '/about', hash: '#team' })


const userId = '123'
router.push({ name: 'user', params: { userId } }) // -> /user/123
router.push({ path: `/user/${userId}` }) // -> /user/123
// This will NOT work
router.push({ path: '/user', params: { userId } }) // -> /user
```