# Vue-router change meta name with property

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router

I want to change the meta attribute inside my .vue file. The problem is, I am only sending the id property but I want the name to be the `meta.name`. I tried the solution from phil ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46838665/vue-router-dynamically-set-meta)) but it didn't worked out.

So far I got a simple router and a vue file:
router.js

```js
      {
        path: ":id",
        name: "singleBook",
        component: BookList,
        meta: { name: "Book" },
      },
```

```js
<template>
    <p> {{ $route.meta.name }} </p>
</template>
//...
<script>
const route = useRoute();

const props = defineProps({
  data: Object,
});
</script>
```

Now I tried to access the meta field with `route.meta.name` and overwrite the current value `'Book'` with the `props.data.name` value. Unfortunately I don't know how to do this.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but can't you just use ```router.replace```, i.e.  router.replace({ meta: { name: "new value"}}) ? https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#replace-current-location

Comment: This changes nothing for me :/ @ThomasKuhlmann

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider `vue-meta` plugin. Also try check on your guard/lifecycle WHEN you exactly change your meta. I think you should consider changing it before any dom-loads. Not sure if this works but it feels like it's worth considering.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).